# iOS: Set tweet recipient

Tags: ios5, twitter

I know how to tweet a message using the standard iOS 5 twitter framework (using the code bellow). I do not know:

a) If it is possible to send a tweet to a specific recipient (myself). I would like to do this as a "Contact Us" feature in my app so the user can message me.

b) If there is a way to make the user follow me on Twitter.

Thanks in advance!

```
-(IBAction)twitter:(id)sender {

if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
{
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet =
    [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:
     @"About my app"];
    [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                              message:@"No Internet Connection"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a, send a reply:

```
[tweetSheet setInitialText:
 @"@pantelisproios About my app"];
```

b, follow by sending a tweet:

```
[tweetSheet setInitialText:
 @"follow pantelisproios"];
```

You can also use TWRequest if you want to use the twitter API directly.